# Find p and q s.t. $({p-1})^{q-1}+({q-1})^{p-1} \equiv 101 \pmod {pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is:

**Find two distinct odd primes p and q such that  $({p-1})^{q-1}+({q-1})^{p-1} \equiv 101 \pmod {pq}$**
Well...
I only have the idea to write down

> ${p-1}^{q-1} \equiv -1^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$

Actually, I solve this question by brute force and get p=11 q=3; however, I wanna know some wise solutions...

Mine is .... a bad one

Please help me to solve this question :(

Comment: The "brute force" approach worked, perhaps because you were clever enough to try setting one of the unknowns to the smallest possible odd prime $q=3$.  If there is a motive to discuss a more sophisticated approach,  perhaps you can describe that.

Answer (score 3):

Taking your equation mod $p$,

$$(-1)^{q-1} + (q-1)^{p-1} \equiv 101 \ (\text{mod }p)$$
But $q$ is an odd prime, so $(-1)^{q-1} = 1$, and thus $(q-1)^{p-1} \equiv 100 \ (\text{mod }p)$.  Similarly $(p-1)^{q-1} \equiv 100 \ (\text{mod }q)$.  Now use Fermat's "little" theorem (but don't forget the case where $p$ or $q$ is $5$).

Comment: Why is the case where p or q is 5 special?

Comment: Because $5$ divides $100$.