# Find out p and q s.t. $({p-1})^{q-1}+({q-1})^{p-1}\equiv 101\pmod{pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

p and q are odd primes. I know I should use Fermat's little theorem, but truly I have no idea how to use it. May someone help me how to apply this theorem in this problem, or maybe give me some hints about it? $({p-1})^{q-1}+({q-1})^{p-1}\equiv 101\pmod{pq}$
[Find p and q s.t. $({p-1})^{q-1}+({q-1})^{p-1} \equiv 101 \pmod {pq}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388993/find-p-and-q-s-t-p-1q-1q-1p-1-equiv-101-pmod-pq)
i think i should explain why i would ask this again since i can get the below method of using Fermat's little theorem to get the solution of p and q.

Comment: i just can't understand the statement in that context

Comment: could i ask you how to use Fermat's little theorem to get solution to p and q?