# $({p-1})^{q-1}+({q-1})^{p-1}\equiv 101\pmod{pq}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

[Find p and q s.t. $({p-1})^{q-1}+({q-1})^{p-1} \equiv 101 \pmod {pq}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388993/find-p-and-q-s-t-p-1q-1q-1p-1-equiv-101-pmod-pq/3402794?noredirect=1#comment6999469_3402794)
I have a question about the first answer of professor Robert Israel. I can't get it how to use Fermat's little theorem to find the solutions to p and q in the last step. Besides, why would we need to deal carefully with the case p or q is 5?
And, this is the original problem $({p-1})^{q-1}+({q-1})^{p-1}\equiv 101\pmod{pq}$, where p and q are odd primes.

Comment: Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Yes, if p is prime and a isn't divided by p, then  $({a})^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. but i still can't get how to use this to construct a solution.

Comment: You have $(p - 1)^{q - 1} \equiv 100 \pmod q$

but by Fermat, and if $q \nmid p - 1$, $$(p - 1)^{q -1} \equiv 1 \pmod q$$

What can you conclude?

Comment: why q can't divide $p - 1$? if p be 23 and q be 11, then surely q could divide $p - 1$

Comment: Exactly.

That's why you need the two congruences. Since either $p \nmid q - 1$ or $q \nmid p - 1$.

Comment: but how could i get such congruences.

Comment: From Fermat's, since either $p\nmid q - 1$ or $q \nmid p - 1$ you'll have either $$(p - 1)^{q - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod q$$
or $$(q - 1)^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
(ofcourse it may not both, if you ask again I'll write it as an answer)

Comment: ohoh, i wanna ask how you get either  p∤q−1 or q∤p−1(the assumption)

Comment: Oh that? that's trivial,

since one of them must be greater than the other atleast $2$,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got that 
\begin{equation}
(p - 1)^{q - 1} \equiv 100 \pmod q \tag{*}
\end{equation}
and $$(q -1)^{p - 1} \equiv 100 \pmod p.$$
Assume without loss of generality that $p < q.$  Then $p - 1 < q$ so $q\nmid p - 1$. From Fermat's Little Theorem we got $$(p - 1)^{q - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod q.$$

From this and (*), we must have $$100 \equiv 1 \pmod q\implies 99 \equiv 0 \pmod q.$$
That is, $q$ is a factor of $99$.

Comment: i get it why it would be at least p∤q−1 or q∤p−1, thank you very much. Thus, we can't find out such solution to satisfy that equation.

Comment: @Andrew It has. Like you said, $(p,q) = (3,11),(11,3)$ are the solutions.

Comment: oh, i know how to construct such solution.  $({p-1})^{q-1}\equiv 100\pmod{q}$ if q is equal to 3, then this won't violate Fermat's little thm.

Comment: @Andrew Correct!

Comment: by the assumption(without loss of generality), q need bigger than p, so q can only be 11

Comment: @Andrew Note that there is also a solution $\,5,11\,$ which is not explicitly addressed above (but the OP asks only for one solution).